# Are there issues installing Ubuntu onto Virtuall Box?

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to download Ubuntu onto Virtual Box. When I get past the initial set up (partitioning, region selection, user creation), the OS goes into the install phase, where "Saving Installed packages..." text appears at the bottom. It stays like this, with no real progression into the download. It has been like this for hours.

Comment: I'm involved with QA-testing and issues are almost non-existent (and if they are impacting me, it's because of problems with the daily image which will impact everyone, not a released image). Did you do the basics of validating the ISO?  You didn't say what release, but I always use a modern OS & `virtualbox` (currently `6.1.20-dfsg-1`) and have allocated enough resources for the test (virtualbox can fail to unsquash if not giving enough RAM which Oracle have declared is a end-user error, not `virtualbox` issue)   You gave no specifics at all, so currently reads like user-error

Answer (score 1):

Which version of ubuntu you are trying to install?
It seems this error happens when you wrongly make partitions for your OS you want to install.
Please install Ubuntu one time with default partitioning and see if the problem still exist or not! if the OS installed correctly in this way, you are probably doing wrong partitioning.

For default partitioning, in the "Installation type" page, choose the first option:

[image: SCREEN SHOT OF Default choice for partitions in installation progress.]

Comment: I've never had and issue installing Ubuntu using the default partitioning like you mention. Very good advice to try it that way first!